# data sheet reading

Tags: datasheet

If I were to use a RF of 2500MHz, would I consider the typical value of 8 or the typical value of 7.4?

[image]

[link to datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/5542f.pdf)

Comment: You even might "derate" by 2/5 of 8-7.4: MIN 6.3, TYP 7.8 dB. (For any information content, you would have some band (if narrow compared to IF), not a single frequency. If wide, just take the number(s) for 2.65 GHz.)

Comment: Depends on what you are using the value for? Minimum considerations? Typicall performance? Want to play safe? Has to work somehow? Has to work every time? .... And so on

Answer (score 2):

> If I were to use a RF of 2500MHz, would I consider the typical value of 8 or the typical value of 7.4?

If you really want to consider 'typical' values, then maybe you should interpolate, by default linearly, between 2.4 GHz and 2.65 GHz, to get roughly 7.7 dB.

However, having done that, or better still before you do that, you should ask yourself do you want a typical value, or the range in which the gain is likely to occur?

At 2.4 GHz, there is a whole 1.5dB range between the minimum and the typical value. You might guess that there's a maximum gain above the typical that you will see sometimes, so maybe there's a 3dB range between minimum and maximum (or maybe more?)

If you are building several devices, do you want them all to work wherever the gain falls in this possible 3dB range, or just the ones with typical gain?

That 0.3dB gain difference between typical for 2.4, 2.5 or 2.65 GHz looks quite unimportant compared with the maybe 3dB gain variation at any given frequency.